# Spring application not creating the table on a MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Spring doesn't create the table specified in my `@Entity` class in my MySQL database.

I've tried a lot of solutions given here in StackOverflow, like some changes in the application.properties, changing the dialect, setting up the schema etc. I've checked my database permissions and also the user/password information, and it's all fine.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyBank?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBanc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyBanc</name>
    <description>JEE spring boot Web Project by Zied </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Client.java**

```
package com.example.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long code;
    private String nom;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Compte> comptes;

    public Client() {
        super();
    }

    public Client(String nom, String email) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<Compte> getComptes() {
        return comptes;
    }

    public void setComptes(Collection<Compte> comptes) {
        this.comptes = comptes;
    }
}
```

**terminal:**

```
2019-12-16 14:24:38.857  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.MyBank.MyBankApplication     : Starting MyBankApplication on DESKTOP-BLK0G7N with PID 6812 (C:\Users\ziedb\OneDrive\Bureau\aa\MyBank\target\classes started by Zied BenOthman in C:\Users\ziedb\OneDrive\Bureau\aa\MyBank)
2019-12-16 14:24:38.862  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.MyBank.MyBankApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-16 14:24:38.935  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\ziedb\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/ziedb/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2019-12-16 14:24:38.936  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-12-16 14:24:38.936  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-12-16 14:24:39.539  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-12-16 14:24:39.557  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2019-12-16 14:24:39.809  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-16 14:24:40.083  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-16 14:24:40.091  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-16 14:24:40.091  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2019-12-16 14:24:40.169  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-16 14:24:40.169  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1233 ms
2019-12-16 14:24:40.288  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2019-12-16 14:24:40.346  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2019-12-16 14:24:40.469  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-12-16 14:24:40.627  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-12-16 14:24:40.754  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-12-16 14:24:40.769  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-12-16 14:24:40.977  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-12-16 14:24:40.984  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-12-16 14:24:41.019  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-12-16 14:24:41.072  WARN 6812 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-12-16 14:24:41.236  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-16 14:24:41.388  WARN 6812 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2019-12-16 14:24:41.550  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-12-16 14:24:41.553  INFO 6812 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.MyBank.MyBankApplication     : Started MyBankApplication in 3.075 seconds (JVM running for 3.971)
```

Based on the tutorial that I'm following, this setup should result in the creation of the table in the *MySQL* database, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: can you try to change : spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Can you share your class main ?

Comment: package com.sid;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBankApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MyBankApplication.class, args);
 }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible causes for this:

- The application.properties file is not in the correct location. It
  should be located in src/main/resources
- Second problem: The entity class. You should add @Column on top of
  the attributes
- Move the entity package to become like org.example.entities and run
  the app

In spring application you should create one pakcage for the one layer(entity, repository,service ...)

Comment: I fixed my issue with your last bullet point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this to achieve first a JDBC CRUD:

1. Remove all the unnecessary  maven dependencies, only have following to begin with :

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <!-- MySQL connector -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <!-- in case you wanna add Junits-->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.22.0</version>
       </plugin>

   </plugins>
   ```
2. Then have following in your **application.properties**

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:**yourMySQLPort**/MyBank?serverTimezone=UTC
>   spring.datasource.username=root
>   
> spring.datasource.password=
>   
> spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
>   
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

3. Take care of auto-generation of id of your entity:

   @Entity
      public class Client implements Serializable {

   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long code;
      ...
4. And to keep things simple initially, maintain the Main class i.e Spring boot starter class annotated  with **@SpringBootApplication** in the same package as your entity **Client**

I've noticed that you haven't mentioned the MySQL server port in your URL, see if thats something that is not initiating the connection. Once you get this sorted, you can add up the rest of the features in your app (thymeleaf based viewing tech etc)

Hope this helps!